# Google BigQuery - Custom quota for each user

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there any way to set up a custom quota for each user?

Example:

- User1 = 10 Tb,
- User2 = 20 Tb
- User3 (Project owner) = unlimited

Comment: Find a step by step plus pics on https://stackoverflow.com/a/52831057/132438

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a default feature to preform this, but it is possible to export your billing to another Big Query table and keep a track of each user consumption. A very good example of this excercise is shown by Mike Zinni. https://medium.com/google-cloud/visualize-gcp-billing-using-bigquery-and-data-studio-d3e695f90c08

With this feed Cloud Functions with a result of consumption and revoke a user.

This solution might have several hours of delay before revoking the permission.

Answer (score 2):

I like Nilo's answer - meanwhile you could also leverage BigQuery's cost controls:

- When you run a query there are at least 2 projects involved: The project used to run the query (costs go here), and the project/dataset containing the data (which could be the same project too).
- You can set up cost controls that apply to every user in one project. You can give users in said project permission to query data which lives in a different project. For users in this project, set up a custom quota (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/cost-controls).
- For different group of users, make them members of different projects. Each of these projects can have a different custom quota per user. Then give them all permission to query the project containing the data.

Comment: Thanks, kind a complicated way to do so easy thing :-(

Comment: The team loves feature requests, and chiming in prioritizes them higher! https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/559654

Comment: I´m sorry if this will look too groupie. But I cannot believe that Felipe Hoffa just said "I like Nilo's answer"!!!! *Mic dropped*

Comment: @Nilo_DS I laughed out loud here xD!! hehehe