# How do I turn on cost controls on BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Self managed cost controls in BigQuery are GA now! At least according to this blog post:

- https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/whats-happening-bigquery-new-ingest-format-data-type-updates-ml-and-query-scheduling

Which links to these docs:

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/custom-quotas

Which link to this console page:

- https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas

But I can't figure out how to set this up... Help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Go to the console URL (https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas)
- Make sure you have the right project selected

[image]

- Filter the quotas to focus on BigQuery

[image]

- Check the box for "query usage per day"

[image]

- Click "EDIT QUOTAS"

[image]

- Set up your email, phone number.
- Enter your daily limit in TiB (teras)

[image]

- Click "Done", "Submit request".
- Stay calm, and keep querying!

Comment: How can you use this to set quotas at the user/account level?
E.g. to limit a service account's maximum bytes queried on BigQuery. thanks!