# Google BigQuery rate limiting Tableau

Tags: google-bigquery

Google BigQuery is refusing the connection because the rate limit has been exceeded.

We are a paying customer of Google BigQuery, and therefore this should not be happening. The message is passed from Google to Tableau and is: "Quota exceeded: Your project exceeded quota for free query bytes scanned." However I can happily run queries through Google's UI but Tableau does not let me proceed. Can you please advise how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: How about engaging GCP support ?

Comment: "Your project exceeded quota for free query bytes scanned" - means you are using a project without a billing account - your queries will be limited to a free terabyte every month. Consider using a project that has billing enabled, and please remember to turn on your cost controls. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52831057/132438

Answer (score 0):

Since the error message shows: "Quota exceeded: Your project exceeded quota for free query bytes scanned.", you should enable billing for the project so that you're not hitting the [free query quota](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#free). Though you're paying customer of Google BigQuery, but it might happen that this specific project is not billing enabled.