# How do I turn on cost controls at user level on BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Felipe Hoffa wrote [this very helpful guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52831056/how-do-i-turn-on-cost-controls-on-bigquery) on how to turn on custom cost control for a project in BigQuery. However, according to the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/custom-quotas), it should be possible to configure custom cost control as user level as well. I really need to do this for my production data warehouse project because I can't let one person's mishap stop all the other users from using the data warehouse. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to console.cloud.google.com > I&AM > Quotas. Then filter by bigquery in the services dropdown. You will find a row like the one bellow:

[image]

You are looking to edit the Query usage per day per user. To calculate the number of Bytes you can use a service like: https://convertlive.com/u/convert/terabytes/to/bytes#1

Comment: That is magic. I'm pretty sure last time I looked (about a month ago) I only saw the 'Query usage per day' row and definitely not the 'Query usage per day per user' row!