# How to save costs when calling BigQuery from a Google Cloud Function

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I have 10,000 images added to my google storage bucket on a daily basis.

This bucket has a cloud function event which triggers BigQuery scans

My cloud function checks for existing records in BigQuery 10,000 times a day, which is running up my BigQuery bill to unsustainable amount.

I would like to know if there is a way to query the database once and store the results into a variable which can then be available for all triggered cloud functions?

In summary: query DB  once, store query results, use query results for all cloud function invocations. This way I do not hit BigQuery 10,000+ times a day.

P.S. BigQuery processed 288 Terabytes of data which is an insane bill $$$$$$$$$$$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an insane bill.

Step 1: Set up cost controls. You will never deal with an insane bill again.

- [How do I turn on cost controls on BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52831056/how-do-i-turn-on-cost-controls-on-bigquery)

Step 2: Instead of querying again, check out the results of the previous job. If it's the same query and data, the same results are still valid. The API method is `jobs.getQueryResults()`.

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/getQueryResults

Step 3: Cluster your tables. You'll probably find 90% additional cost reductions.

- https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-optimized-cluster-your-tables-65e2f684594b

Comment: perfect, exactly what I was looking for :) Thank you very much sir